# Resultset closed exception

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to retrieve results from a DB in a resultset. However i want to execute an update query for each entry in the resultset, but i get an exception.
this is my code

```
try {
      Statement statement = sqlconnection.conn.createStatement();
      query = "select * from reminders where year<= "+ syear +" and month<=" + smonth +" and date<"+ sday +" and reminded like 'false';";
      rs= statement.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()){
          id=rs.getInt("sno");
          String reminder = rs.getString("remind");
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, reminder);
          statement.executeUpdate("update reminders set reminded='true' where sno="+id+";");
      }
```

Can any1 show me a better way of doing this ?? I am pretty new to programming. Hence showing  me how to it will be really helpful.
thanks

Comment: on which line do you get the error ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question... But If this is a production code I see a very big SQL injection problem in your code... Don't build SQL squeries using string concatenation... Use Parameterised queries insted.

Comment: @The King: while generally true, I'd assume all variables to be numeric here. @Samuel_xL: second call to re.next(), I'd bet

Comment: @nicolas : Thanks for pointing it out... It never occured to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still looping over the results from `statement` when you're trying to perform an update with it. I'd try using a second `Statement` object for your updates.

Answer (score 0):

Your ResultSet is not updatable.

```
Statement statement = sqlconnection.conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```